# why BleManager.scan method always return null?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native

I am trying to scan Bluetooth devices in my react native application I have used react-native-ble-manager package to scan.

`alert(this.state.ble)` always return null.

There are some Bluetooth devices available but this method cannot realize
what should I do?

**code:**

```
export default class Setting extends React.Component  {
  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
        ble:null,
        scanning:false,
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.handleDiscoverPeripheral = this.handleDiscoverPeripheral.bind(this);

    NativeAppEventEmitter
        .addListener('BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral', this.handleDiscoverPeripheral );
}

handleScan() {
    BleManager.scan([], 30, true)
        .then((results) => console.log('Scanning...'));
        alert(this.state.ble)

}

toggleScanning(bool){
    if (bool) {
        this.setState({scanning:true})
        this.scanning = setInterval( ()=> this.handleScan(), 3000);
    } else{
        this.setState({scanning:false, ble: null})
        clearInterval(this.scanning);
    }
}

handleDiscoverPeripheral(data){
    console.log('Got ble data', data);
    this.setState({ ble: data })
}

render() {

    const container = {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    }

    const bleList = this.state.ble
        ? <Text> Device found: {this.state.ble.name} </Text>
        : <Text>no devices nearby</Text>

    return (
        <View style={container}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={{padding:20, backgroundColor:'#ccc'}} onPress={() => this.toggleScanning(!this.state.scanning) }>
                <Text>Scan Bluetooth ({this.state.scanning ? 'on' : 'off'})</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            {bleList}
        </View>
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Do you call `BleManager.start()` first?  2. Try `BleManager.scan([], 30)`, allowDuplicates is an IOS only argument and you are tagged android.

Comment: Also, `alert(this.state.ble)` is not in `then` statement so it will be called just after scan is start.  in that moment, there is no device found yet

Comment: I changed my handle function to:   handleScan() {
    BleManager.start().then(
      BleManager.scan([], 30, true)
        .then(results => console.log("Scanning..."))
        .then(alert(this.state.ble))
    );
  } now i am getting alert [object object]

Comment: Better... You are getting object because alert does not stringify json objects. you can call `start` function in componentDidMount and call `scan` with your button. based on document, you can call `getDiscoveredPeripherals` after scan complete to get list of detected devices.

Comment: sorry for asking too many questions Im new to this stuff, where should i add getDiscoveredPeripherals exactly? i added in end of scan handle function and i got this error: cant find variable: getDiscoveredPeripherals

Comment: too many comments are here, may we can talk in private?

Comment: yes where can i send message to you?

Comment: @ali_sn72 on telegram